# How to enable resizable, draggable AND sortable (with connectedSortable) in dynamic unsorted lists

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

The lists are neither sortable or connectedSortable  using this code:

```
$("#button1").click(function(){
     $("<ul />", {
       class: "dynamic sortable_list  connectedSortable", 
       //connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
       text: " Section "+counter,
       id:  counter++
      }).resizable().draggable().addClass("draggable").css('background-color', getColor())
        .sortable()
        .append('<br /><input type="button" class="removeButton" value="Remove"/>')
        .appendTo("body");
    });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow/ This appears to be a `ul` with no `li` elements. Could you provide more of an example.

Comment: THanks Twisty for your comment.

Comment: THanks Twisty for your comment. Take a look at this fiddle ...https://jsfiddle.net/stevenpm/0yc92wpw/1/.   Basically the dynamic lists are not "connectedSortable"  with the static list on the far left. THanks.

Answer (score 0):

Per your comment, I made some minor changes now that I see how it's being used.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/qdt2gp64/1/

Order or operation is important here. It is best to append before initializing sortable and draggable. Also, when you initialize the new sortable, it also needs the `connectWith` option populated.

**JavaScript**

```
  $("#button1").click(function() {
    $("<ul />", {
        class: "dynamic sortable_list connectedSortable",
        text: " Section " + counter,
        id: "Section" + counter++
      })
      .append('<br /><input type="button" class="removeButton" value="Remove"/>')
      .appendTo("body")
      .sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
      })
      .draggable();
  });
```

I am now able to drag an item from left list to the dynamically created list. And I can drag back to it's source.

Comment: THank you very much .. I don't know what I would do without you talented guys ...

Comment: @stevenMatthews Some stuff to consider: https://jsfiddle.net/qdt2gp64/3/ like a handle for the draggable, and ways you can make easy use of UI.